# Error creating Team Project from VS 2010 Ultimate when installed VS 2012 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Today I installed the RTM version of Visual Studio 2012 Web Express on my laptop running Windows 7. On the laptop I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate SP1 installed and Team Foundation Server 2010 SP1. After I've installed VS2012 I can't create new Team Projects from within VS2010 anymore. I receive error message Field not found:

'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.FrameworkServiceIdentifiers.NewTeamProjectWeb'

When I try to create a new Team Project from within VS2012 it works as expected. When I return to VS2010 I have no problem to connect to the Team Project I created from within VS2012.
Is this a bug? Anyone knowing the reason for this behavior or any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

That is by design. In every version of Team Foundation Server there is a lot of new things in the Process Template (in this round for example to support the product backlog), of which the older clients are not aware.

Since creating a team project is performed by the client we block older clients creating new team projects. We have a story on our backlog to create a project on the server (as you can today on tfspreview.com), but there are some dependencies - like SharePoint integration - that  cause technical issues.

Ewald Hofman

TFS Program Manager